# Plotly js Legend size height and width

Tags: javascript, html, css, plot, plotly

I use plotly js to plot some graph the issue that i face is that the legend in some graph hides some of the plot and I need the legend to be inside the plot. Is there a way to make the legend shorter in length and show its content in a list with scrollbar?

I tried to use a `"<br>"` element inside the name that i used to make it less in width but it's not working. Also, I tried to make the font size smaller but it became not readable. Any help?
this is the code inside the LAYOUT

```
 legend: {
      x: 0.99,
      xanchor: 'right',
      y: 0.01,
      font: {
        family: "Poppins",
        size: 10,
        weight: 'bold',
        // color:"#FF5733",
      },
      bgcolor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
      
    },
```